# Push Notification Android with ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send push notifications to my Android device from my server. Using plug PushNotification Cordova, my code is something.

```
        var androidConfig = {
          "senderID": "inspired-berm-101218",
        };

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
          $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
            // Success
          }, function(err) {
            // Error
          })

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
            switch(notification.event) {
              case 'registered':
                if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
                  alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
                  sessionService.set("token_device",notification.regid);
```

My information according to me, I followed advice from this forum and tutorials are good and are these:

Api KEY : AIzaSyDtZndyGvmWXF0TpYe83KVDgxRZ4MR3zK8

ID del proyecto: inspired-berm-101218

Número del proyecto: 805573676421

All this I use both my application and server are the same codes, but nevertheless, I receive the error:

```
{"multicast_id":7843752850335107662,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Try uninstalling the application on my phone and reinstall but nothing, does not this work for me.

Comment: sender id is your project id 805573676421 so change your `var androidConfig = {
          "senderID": "inspired-berm-101218",
        };` to `var androidConfig = {
          "senderID": "805573676421",
        };`

Comment: i create a project and tutorial for this 
https://medium.com/@ezeezegg/push-notification-con-ionic-para-android-81d99e91df42#.gmyimks5k

and the code is available in  https://github.com/ezegg/ionic-push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this website to create and run the application again immediately, it gives the exact data.

[Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/)